# Query based on content of inputbox without submitting

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a "result" inputbox that concatenates two inputboxes every time an onchange event happens on the two inputbox. What i would like to do is to make a mysql query based on the value of "result" inputbox and display its result on another inputbox without clicking a button. Is this possible?

I am trying to do this for more than 4 hours now but still i have no result done on the query part and displaying it on an inputbox

```js
function getdatefinal() {
    var tt = document.getElementById('startfinal').value;
    var months = document.getElementById('termfinal').value;
    document.getElementById('term').value = months;

    var interest = document.getElementById('interest').value;
    var sampledata = interest + '-' + months;
    document.getElementById('sample').value = sampledata;

    var date = new Date($('#startfinal').val());
    day = date.getDate();
    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(date);

    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + (months * 30));

    var dd = day;
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    if (dd > 28 && mm == 2) {
        dd = 28;
    } else if ((dd > 30 && mm == 4) || (dd > 30 && mm == 6) || (dd > 30 && mm == 9) || (dd > 30 && mm == 11)) {
        dd = 30;
    }


    var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
    document.getElementById('endfinal').value = someFormattedDate;
}
```

```html
<table  class="table table-condensed">
     <h5>Final</h5>
            <tr>
          <td><div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><input id ="termfinal" name ="termfinal" type="number" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="getdatefinal()"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8"><input id="frfinal" name="frfinal" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm" readonly  value=""></div></div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8"><input id="mafinal" name="mafinal" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm" readonly  value=""></div></div>
        </td>
         <td><div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8"><input id="fafinal" name="fafinal" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm" readonly  value=""></div></div>
        </td>
         <td><div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-10"><input id="startfinal" name="startfinal" type="date"  class="form-control input-sm"  value="" onchange="getdatefinal()"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10"><input id="endfinal" name="endfinal" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm" readonly  value=""></div></div>
    </td>
      </tr>

</table>

    <div class="form-group">

                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="interest">Interest Rate (%)</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                   <!--  <div class="input-group"> -->
                                           <input id="interest" name="interest" type="number"  class="form-control input-sm"  value="" onchange="getdatefinal()">
             <!--                          <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button  id="interestsubmit" name="interestsubmit" class="btn btn-default">Go!</button>
      </span> -->

                         <!--     </div> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="frate">Sample</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="sample" name="sample" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm"  value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="frate">Factor Rate</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="frate" name="frate" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm"  value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Here is SQL database

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Code        VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Factor_Rate NUMERIC(11,9) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Code,Factor_Rate) VALUES ('1-1',1.01);
INSERT INTO mytable(Code,Factor_Rate) VALUES ('1-2',0.5075);
INSERT INTO mytable(Code,Factor_Rate) VALUES ('1-3',0.34);
```

Comment: "Is this possible?". Yes. You need an ajax query back to the server, which will run the query and return the response. What exactly have you tried so far? I cant see any queries or ajax here.

Comment: I have tried simple query. i have not included it on the code . because i have deleted it already. regarding ajax i have no idea how to cexecute it. using ajax and display it on inputbox

Comment: Have you used ajax before? It might be best to take an introductory tutorial if you're not familiar with it at all, before attempting to use it.

Comment: I am currently studying it right now . could i ask for an example on how to display it on html inputbox ?

Comment: once you get the response from ajax, you can display the value in a box in the normal way e.g. ` document.getElementById('myInputBox').value = data;` (assuming `data` is the value sent back as the response from the ajax request)

Comment: Thank you . I have done it already